# Motorola ES400 barcode scan OnRead Event issue

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, motorola-emdk

I am using Symbol.Barcode and Symbol.Barcode.DesignCF35.dll in Motorola EMDK 2.8.
i  am getting issue of OnRead event of Barcode scanner firing continuously. I have Motorola ES400 windows mobile device.
I have set EnableScanner property as True and BufferSize = 7905 in design view. and i also generate OnRead event form design view.

following is event of Barcdoe

```
        private void barcodeTruck_OnRead(object sender, Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData readerData)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {

                txtVinNumber.Text = readerData.Text;

            readerData.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

    }
```

when i press scan button the OnRead event is fired and it keeps calling that event continuously. and i have set property at design is given in below image.
Dose any one has solution for this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not set your event to "Handled = True"?

Comment: Hi Thanks for Reply. I have generate _OnRead event using design. and in that there is no any property to set "Handled =True". Can you please help me how i generate event for barcode and set property "Handled =True"